# Why is my Excel office object leaving behind EXCEL.exe processes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dispose, office-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp)

I have an application that uses Office Interop libraries for C#.

This library is called from an ASP.NET application hosted with IIS7.

The relevant code bits are:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides excel functions.
/// </summary>
public class ExcelStuff : IDisposable
{
    #region Excel Components

    // The following are pre-allocated Excel objects that must be explicitly disposed of.

    private Excel.Application xApp;
    private Excel.Workbooks xWorkbooks;
    private Excel.Workbook xWorkbook;
    private Excel.Sheets xWorksheets;
    private Excel.Worksheet xWorksheet;
    private Excel.ChartObjects xCharts;
    private Excel.ChartObject xMyChart;
    private Excel.Chart xGraph;
    private Excel.SeriesCollection xSeriesColl;
    private Excel.Series xSeries;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ExcelStuff" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ExcelStuff()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does some work.
    /// </summary>
    public void DoWork()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[0];

        worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Do some work.
        });

        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();

        worker.Abort();
        worker = null;

        Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the current object and cleans up any resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Cleanup
        xWorkbook.Close(false);
        xApp.Quit();

        // Manual disposal because of COM
        xApp = null;
        xWorkbook = null;
        xWorksheets = null;
        xWorksheet = null;
        xCharts = null;
        xMyChart = null;
        xGraph = null;
        xSeriesColl = null;
        xSeries = null;

        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

You will notice a lot of redundancies in the code, which are my desperate attempt to solve this problem. **So please don't tell me that it's inefficient to call `GC.Collect()` or that calling `Dispose()` from within the class isn't good - I know these things already.**

What I would like to know is, why this code keeps orphaned `EXCEL.exe` processes running on the server when I'm doing my best to clean up as many objects as possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp Marhsal.ReleaseComObject is your friend.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1884217/88672

Comment: Microsoft itself advises not to do this see discussion and links in accepted answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1804781.aspx/1

Comment: @Bill No. I have Office installed on the server, I have an App Pool running as a desktop user account, and my ASP.NET project can open the files just fine. The problem is with COM disposal, it has little to do with ASP/IIS configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone mentioned in a comment, Marshal.ReleaseComObject is what I use to clean up excel objects. Here is a sample of my code:

```
        wb.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb) != 0)
        { }

        excelApp.Quit();

        while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp) != 0)
        { }
```

This seems to work for me. Good luck!

**EDIT:** Sorry, didn't see this was a dup. Mods can do whatever with this...

Comment: Don't worry, I accepted it anyway, it's the correct answer.